# how to extract numbers from string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to extract numbers from string using Javascript?
Test cases below:

```
string s = 1AA11111 
string s1= 2111CA2

string s result  = 111111 
string s1 result = 211112
```

My code below is not working:

```
var j = 0;
var startPlateNums = "";
while (j <= iStartLength && !isNaN(iStartNumber.substring(j, j + 1))){
          startPlateNums = startPlateNums + iStartNumber.substring(j, j + 1);
           j++;
}
```

Comment: what is `iStartLength` initialized to ? Also, what is `iStartNumber` ?

Comment: Your  `while` loop will break as soon as a non-number is encountered (`isNaN` becomes `true`). Looking at your sample input and output, that's not what you want. You probably want to move that condition into an `if` block inside your loop.

Answer (score 4):

How about a simple regexp

```
s.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

or as stated in the comments

```
s.replace(/\D/g, '')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2mguE/

Comment: I was going to post `/\D/g`.  Saves 1 character!

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Saves more than 1, it saves 3 ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do:
**EDITED:**

```
var num = "123asas2342a".match(/[\d]+/g)
console.log(num);
// THIS SHOULD PRINT ["123","2342"]
```

Comment: That will fail for numbers that comes after non-numeric characters.

Comment: It would require a global flag: `"123asas2342a".match(/\d+/g) # => ["123", "2342"]`, but +1 for matching and not just replacing everything that's not a number with an empty string `''`

Comment: You may want `('...'.match(/\d+/g) || []).join('')` just in case there are no digits

Answer (score 1):

A regex replace would probably the easiest and best way to do it:

```
'2111CA2'.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

However here's another alternative without using regular expressions:

```
var s = [].filter.call('2111CA2', function (char) {
    return !isNaN(+char);
}).join('');
```

Or with a simple for loop:

```
var input = '2111CA2',
    i = 0,
    len = input.length,
    nums = [],
    num;

for (; i < len; i++) {
    num = +input[i];
    !isNaN(num) && nums.push(num);
}

console.log(nums.join(''));
```