# Extract a number from a string? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

```
var amount = "(21)";
```

How would I go about just getting the number? I have gotten it to work with...

```
var amountResult = amount.substring(1, amount.length-1);
```

...but that just feels incorrect.

What's the better, more flexible way to do this if it were not always surrounded by just 2 characters?

Thanks!

Comment: For something that simple I think a couple of trivial string calls are better than an regex. You could also; `parseInt(amount.substr(1), 10)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to extract numbers from string using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989872/how-to-extract-numbers-from-string-using-javascript) and [many more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+extract+number+from+string).

Comment: Oh so horrible: `var amount = "(21)"; var num = new Function("return " + amount + ";")();`, but I had to share.

Comment: @epascarello well for that matter, `var num = eval(amount);` -- but yeah, I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is much more flexible:

```
var amountResult = amount.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

And to actually turn it into an number:

```
var amountResult = parseInt(amount.match(/\d+/)[0], 10);
```